# Vue failing to resolve components in a very irregular way

Tags: vuejs3

I have `App.vue`:

```html
<template>
  <test/>
  <test-two/>
</template>

<script>
import Test from './components/Test.vue'
import TestTwo from './components/TestTwo.vue'

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    Test,
    TestTwo
  }
}
</script>
```

`components/Test.vue`

```html
<template>
    <test-two/>
</template>

<script>
import TestTwo from './TestTwo.vue'

export default {
    name: 'test',
    components: [
        TestTwo
    ]
}
</script>
```

`components/TestTwo.vue`

```html
<template>
    <span>I test!!!</span>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'test-two',
}
</script>
```

I'm get the warning

```
[Vue warn]: Failed to resolve component: test-two 
  at <Test> 
  at <App>
```

But the direct mention of `<test-two>` in `App.vue` seems to be working. Why might this be?

The project has been freshly scaffold using vue-cli.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a syntax error in your `Test.vue`, components are declared as array but should be object:

```
components: [
    TestTwo
]
```

Should be:

```
components: {
    TestTwo
}
```